# Editing bad lines in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file as following:

```
fruit, country,  city
banana, japan, tokyo
apple, brazil, rio
apple, korea, south, seoul
banana, denmark, copenhagen
```

This is an example, in reality, I have this issue in multiple large files. The issue being I can not read the 4th row with a comma delimiter as it will have one column too much.

My idea is to

1. open the file with csv.reader
2. find rows with term1 in column 2 and term2 in column 3 (in my example, term1=korea and term2=south)
3. Replace term1 in column 2 with term1 and term2 combined (korea south) and deleted the 3rd column in the row
4. save the edited file

In the code below I have completed the first two steps, but I am stuck on step 3 and 4.

```
import csv

path = r'C:\Users\jlobo\Desktop\example.txt'

with open(path, newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_read = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"') #
    
    for row in csv_read:
        search_terms1 = ["korea"]
        search_terms2 = ["south"]

        if any([term in row[1] for term in search_terms1]) and any([term in row[2] for term in search_terms2]):
            print(row)
```

How can I do steps 3 and 4? Or if relevant is there an alternative solution to the problem?

Comment: This is my first post, so any comments on best practices are welcomed

Comment: Do you know how you can write a new CSV file at all (without considering steps 2 and 3)?

Comment: Hi, just to be sure, I suppose a simple search and replace ('korea, south' -> 'korea south') would'nt do?

Comment: If the terms are there like that `korea, south`, what happened is that you're missing the quotation marks, so most likely you shouldn't join them by removing the comma, but leave the comma and add quotation marks around the two terms like `"korea, south"`. I see that you also specify `quotechar='"'`, so that should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define a list `ARRAY = []`, and then while you process the rows append them to that array

```
search_terms1 = ["korea"]
search_terms2 = ["south"]

if any([term in row[1] for term in search_terms1]) and any([term in row[2] for term in search_terms2]):
    row[1] =  row[2] + row[1] # combie south and korea
    row.pop(2) # remove the 3rd element

ARRAY.append(row)
```

And then you can write the file again

```
with open("new_file.csv", "w") as f:
    for row in ARRAY: # Write each row
        f.write(", ".join(row))
        f.write("\n") # add a new line
```

I do not really know how `csv.reader` works, and there may be some functions that do the job better than this, But the snippet above should work just fine.

Comment: Why not just split the array?

Comment: What do you mean split an array? Do you mean join? Now that I see `f.write(", ".join(row))` is better.